# React router: exact doesn't work with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting error on exact:

```
<Switch>
 <Route path="/a" exact component={() => <div>Home page</div>}</Route> 
</Switch>
```

error is:

```
Type '{ path: string; exact: true; component: () => Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<RouteProps, any, any>> & Readonly<RouteProps> & Readonly<...>'.
Property 'exact' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<RouteProps, any, any>> & Readonly<RouteProps> & Readonly<...>'.ts(2322)
```

So, what's going on?
I'm importing components from `react-router-dom`. And also have `@types` for it. In the index.d.ts there is no `exact?: Boolean` for RouteProps.

Comment: Did you try updating your react-router-dom and its @types package version to the latest one?

Comment: yes, i did @AjeetShah

Comment: It exists for version 5+ as seen here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-router/index.d.ts#L92